# You don't have permission to access / on this server Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Some of the users are getting this 403 error when connecting to the AppEngine server:

```
Permission denied
You don't have permission to access / on this server
```

It's quit hard for me to debug this error because I can't reproduce it, and when I searched for the error it seems like a server rooting problem with apache ? Have anyone got this problem with Google AppEngine ?

Comment: By connecting you mean via http/https? If only some users have this problem, it's either a firewall (are you blocking some IP addresses?) or a cache problem.

Comment: We are connected through the same network and I am not blocking IP addresses. Even after clearing the cache the problem is persisting :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Got it, that was due to the `login: admin` row in the app.yaml file letting only admins to access the application. My bad !!

Comment: Glad you found it!